# Facebook #hashtag feeds

Tags: facebook, hashtag

I want a news feeds on facebook in my site that show only the wallpost that have a specific {#hashtag}.

For Example I want to show only my wallpost that has #thankyou.
I'm newbie so please give a sample code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isnt any exact API to get the **hashtag** posts,you may try using search API with `q=%23hashtag`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23hashtag&type=post&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**For getting wall posts and newsfeeds**

**/user/home** The user's news feed.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=%23hashtag&type=post&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**/user/feed** The user's wall.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?q=%23hashtag&type=post&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Permissions** :read_stream

Comment: i got this error (#200) Permissions error. thanks for reply

Comment: Oh thank agian i got the token now but i want only to show my post in a wall or feeds that i posted with specific {#hashtag}.

Comment: yes its helps thanks but it search all the have (for example #StarComm) its search all even i didn't post it. i want only my post that have that hashtag.

Comment: oh its works thanks I have the data now, how do i convert it in facebook format? I know im asking too much but if you like too answer thanks. if not its ok. :)

Comment: Please confirm on what you meant by 'facebook format'? Stackoverflow is not supporting much chats through comments. :)

Comment: Oh sorry i meant that like the GUI of the facebook wall by the result of JSON format (https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?q=%23hashtag&type=post&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}). Do i need to download themes or what? example (http://starcomm.com.ph/try.JPG)

Comment: @zero, How can you resolve (#200) Permissions error? Actualy I stuck on this issue.